# IIS 7 Mutiple websites with url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have 3 Asp.Net MVC 4 web applications. I deployed one on the Default Web site and other 2 as web applications under Default Web site. How can I create bindings so that when I go to http://app.xyz.com/ it will go to first application and then if I do http://app.xyz.com/App2, it should go to 2nd app and so on. Right now I can browse the first application correctly after editing the binding, but when I browse  http://app.xyz.com/App2, I cannot.

can I have the url part (/App2) in the host name of the bindings?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) **No**. You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or explain your issue showing the relevant code.

Comment: I guess, you do not work in IIS and .net :( and are you running after my questions for down voting :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for Virtual Applications, this should give you the effect you're looking for.  Please look at http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis for more details.